# Redux dispatch is not removing an item from the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to remove an item from an array, the redux logger shows that everything went well.

[image]

However it still shows under the ordered list, after i click the x.

[image]

**Reducer/posts.js**

```
    case 'REMOVE_POST': {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        posts: [...state.posts.filter(post=> post.id !== action.id)],
      });

      }

      default:
        return state
  }
```

**components/TodoList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { deletePost } from '../actions'

const PostList = ({posts, deletePost}) => (
  <ul className="list-group">
    {posts.map(post=>
      <li
       className="list-group-item" key={post.id} {...post}>  {post.text}
       <button type="submit" onClick={()=> deletePost(post.id)} className =" btn btn-small-primary"> X </button>
      </li>

    )}

  </ul>


);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { posts: state.posts };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  deletePost: id => dispatch(deletePost(id))
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

**Updated.**

[image]

```
**ADD_POST reducer**

case 'ADD_POST':
  return [
    ...state,
    {
      id:action.id,
      text:action.text,
    }

  ]
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the demo?

Comment: Or at least show the contents of the array

Comment: i updated it. maybe this gives insight.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a small mistake in your code

The action that you have dispatched is `DELETE_POST` whereas you expect `REMOVE_POST` in your code

```
case 'DELETE_POST': {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        posts: [...state.posts.filter(post=> post.id !== action.id)],
      });

      }

      default:
        return state
```

Comment: This should be 
`case 'ADD_POST': return { ...state, posts: [...state.posts, { id:action.id, text:action.text, } ] }`

Comment: check my comment above, you ADD_POST is also not correct

Comment: That would be because of other errors in your code, your state is an object and post is a key in it, that is what it seems from your DELETE_POST code, if its not the case, the DELETE_POST needs to be changed. In any case, I would like to know what is the initial state in your reducer

Comment: would it be possible to update the code, im having trouble understanding the inline code.

Comment: Sure, please update your reducer code with ADD_POST and REMOVE_POST together with the initial state and I shall update my answer according to that

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, thanks you folks for your contributions.

```
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_POST':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id:action.id,
          text:action.text,
        }

      ]

    case 'DELETE_POST':
      return state.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.id);

    default:
      return state
  }

}
```